# OpenVPN clients can connect to anything on the LAN except the OpenVPN server?

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, openvpn, pfsense

I have OpenVPN running on pfSense 2.3.2. Right now I have it mostly working except for one small thing: I can connect to anything on my LAN *except* the pfSense server itself.

Some details:

- I'm configured using 172.16.104.0/21 as an IP address range.
- The firewall sits at 172.16.104.1.
- The DHCP range for OpenVPN clients is 172.16.105.10-50.
- OpenVPN is configured using tap, UDP.
- ovpns1 is assigned to OPT1 and OPT1 and LAN are bridged (bridge0).

The reason I'm using tap and bridging is because I have a lot of Apple devices and want Bonjour and other multicast/broadcast based things to work properly across the VPN.

All this works correctly for any address on my LAN network except 172.16.104.1 (the firewall). None of the clients can ping or connect to 172.16.104.1 and 172.16.104.1 cannot ping or connect to any of the clients.

Using tcpdump reveals some other weirdness:

If I ping the server from a client with tcpdump running in another session, it seems that I'm getting replies but they're not being reported by ping?

```
ping -c2 172.16.104.1
PING 172.16.104.1 (172.16.104.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 172.16.104.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1009ms
```

But in the tcpdump session on the same machine:

```
IP 172.16.105.3 > 172.16.104.1: ICMP echo request, id 17069, seq 1, length 64
IP 172.16.104.1 > 172.16.105.3: ICMP echo reply, id 17069, seq 1, length 64
IP 172.16.105.3 > 172.16.104.1: ICMP echo request, id 17069, seq 2, length 64
IP 172.16.104.1 > 172.16.105.3: ICMP echo reply, id 17069, seq 2, length 64
```

And from the pfSense server:

```
tcpdump -n -i ovpns1 -t icmp
tcpdump: WARNING: ovpns1: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ovpns1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
IP 172.16.105.3 > 172.16.104.1: ICMP echo request, id 17084, seq 1, length 64
IP 172.16.104.1 > 172.16.105.3: ICMP echo reply, id 17084, seq 1, length 64
IP 172.16.105.3 > 172.16.104.1: ICMP echo request, id 17084, seq 2, length 64
IP 172.16.104.1 > 172.16.105.3: ICMP echo reply, id 17084, seq 2, length 64
```

This is an Ubuntu Linux machine with no firewall.

So the pfSense machine is thinks its sending a reply, the Linux machine thinks it's receiving a reply, but ping still reports 100% packet loss?

And if I ping a different, non-server address, I get a response:

```
ping -c2 172.16.104.2
PING 172.16.104.2 (172.16.104.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.104.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=34.6 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.104.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=34.1 ms

--- 172.16.104.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 34.165/34.401/34.638/0.300 ms
```

And in the tcpdump shell:

```
IP 172.16.105.3 > 172.16.104.2: ICMP echo request, id 17068, seq 1, length 64
IP 172.16.104.2 > 172.16.105.3: ICMP echo reply, id 17068, seq 1, length 64
IP 172.16.105.3 > 172.16.104.2: ICMP echo request, id 17068, seq 2, length 64
IP 172.16.104.2 > 172.16.105.3: ICMP echo reply, id 17068, seq 2, length 64
```

Here's my OpenVPN server config dumped from pfSense:

```
dev ovpns1
verb 1
dev-type tap
dev-node /dev/tap1
writepid /var/run/openvpn_server1.pid
#user nobody
#group nobody
script-security 3
daemon
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
proto udp
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
up /usr/local/sbin/ovpn-linkup
down /usr/local/sbin/ovpn-linkdown
local <omitted>
tls-server
server-bridge 172.16.104.1 255.255.248.0 172.16.105.10 172.16.105.50
client-config-dir /var/etc/openvpn-csc/server1
tls-verify "/usr/local/sbin/ovpn_auth_verify tls '<omitted>' 1"
lport 1194
management /var/etc/openvpn/server1.sock unix
push "route 172.16.104.0 255.255.248.0"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
ca /var/etc/openvpn/server1.ca
cert /var/etc/openvpn/server1.cert
key /var/etc/openvpn/server1.key
dh /etc/dh-parameters.1024
tls-auth /var/etc/openvpn/server1.tls-auth 0
persist-remote-ip
float
mode server
```

And from the client:

```
dev tap
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote <omitted> 1194 udp
lport 0
verify-x509-name "<omitted>" name
pkcs12 udp-1194.p12
tls-auth udp-1194-tls.key 1
ns-cert-type server
```

What on earth is going on here?